# Typeform embeded forms and linked forms

Tags: typeform

Is it possible to make the redirected page load within the exisiting embedded frame?

I am trying to connect two forms where the one form redirect to the other, however I would like them both to be embedded on the existing page. As it is now, the 2nd form will load as a new page which is not the intention.

Best Jacob

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As the Typeform team may probably have already told you, Redirection after completion is not supported when embedded. Mainly for security reason.

If you want to achieve this behavior can look at using the [Typeform Embed SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typeform/embed)
embed the first form with it and use the `onSubmit` callback to update the div with the URL of form #2.

But with this solution, you can't pass data from form #1 to form #2. If you want you would have to make an API call to Typeform to retrieve details of the response submitted in form #1 and pass them as hidden fields in #2.